# Best way for Audit in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, audit

I am creating an application where users can create games. I am storing in the entity *Game* who was the user that created the game, I mean, the owner of the game. The entity *Game* has some relationships ONE_TO_ONE (*RuleGame*) and ONE_TO_MANY (*PublicZone* and *PrivateZones*) to other entities.

What I want is that only the owner of the game and users with ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_STAFF be able to edit the game and its relationships.

Another way to say this, think like a Social Network, just me and the ADMIN can edit my profile but I cannot edit the profile of other users.

Of course I can create my own logic in a @Service and in each "update" method of the controller of those entities (*Game*,  *PublicZone* and *PrivateZones*) call it and check this but I am wondering is there is a better way to go.

I was reading about Audit, like Hibernate Envers, but it is for wiki-like software, log who added/updated/deleted, so it doesnt fit in what I need.

I am using Spring 4.1.6, Spring Data Jpa 1.8.0, Spring Security 4 and Hibernate 4.3.8

Every suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Google is your friend:http://blog.countableset.ch/2014/03/08/auditing-spring-data-jpa-java-config/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use [spring-data-jpa auditing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#auditing) along with a security framework such as [spring security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/).  This will allow the username to be added automatically when a record is created and modified with no extra logic from yourself.